# Convert HTML tags to WordML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, wordml

Do you know any way to convert HTML tags to WordML only using JavaScript. I need to get the content of a DOM element and convert what is inside to WordML.

Comment: Do you need to alter it at all or is it essentially valid WordML already?

Comment: I need to alter it. Basically I want to get DOM content, change the markup to valid WordML and create an XML Word document with FileSaver.js.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on npm [there doesn't seem to be a library](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=WordML) for this already.

So I think you're going to have to make your own. That being said, `WordML` is just a particular flavor of XML, right? [This is the WordML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14854/Learning-WordML-Basics) you are referring to?

So to get the content of of a DOM element is pretty easy, you can do that with jQuery.

```
var ele = $('#wordml-element');
```

From there you will now want to convert it into `WordML` compatible `XML`. You could try using the [xml library on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml) for this.

So you will be transforming tree structured DOM elements into tree structured XML elements. The recommended pattern for doing this is known as the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

From there you will be left with an `XML` structure which you can further manipulate using the same pattern. At the end you will convert the `XML` structure into a string and that is what you will save to a file.

Now since I don't really know the structure of the HTML you are trying to convert into `WordML` I can only give you a very general code solution to the problem, which may look something like this:

```
var xml = require('xml')

function onTransformButtonClick() {
  var options = {} // see documentation
  var ele = $('#wordml-element')[0]
  var wordml = transformElement(ele)
  var text = xml(wordml, options);
  fileSave(text);
}

function transformElement(ele) {
  switch(ele.tagName) { // You could use attributes or whatever
    case 'word-document':
      return transformDocument(ele);
    case 'word-body':
      return transformBody(ele);
    case 'word-p':
      return transformParagraph(ele);
    case 'word-r':
      return transformRun(ele);
    case 'word-text':
      return transformText(ele);
  }
}

function transformDocument(ele) {
  var wordDocument = xml.element({...})
  ele.childNodes.forEach(function (child) {
    wordDocument.push(transformElement(child))
  })
  return [wordDocument]
}

function transformBody(ele) {
  // create new element via xml library...
}

function transformParagraph(ele) {
  // create new element via xml library...
}

function transformRun(ele) {
  // create new element via xml library...
}

function transformText(ele) {
  // create new element via xml library...
}
```

The specific implementations of which I will leave up to you since I don't know enough details to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Wouldn't the switch statement be on HTML tags not WordML tags since he wants to convert HTML to WordML? Also I think you'd need to do `ele[0].tagName` as it is a jQuery selector, not a native DOM element.

Comment: This should be switching on the HTML tags yes. You can have elements in html like `<word-document>` if you want but maybe he's using `<div kind="word-document">` I don't know but that would just be a different thing to switch on: `ele.attr('kind')`. The idea is just the visitor pattern on some identifying value. But you're right about `ele[0]`, unless you wanted to use jquery to get the tagname. I will update the snippet.